# Error with inputFrame.gray() opencv android

Tags: android, opencv

This is the code that throws an error:

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame) {
    mrgb=inputFrame.gray();
    return mrgb;
}
```

> return inputFrame.gray(); gray() can not resolve in OpenCv android

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about OpenCV android, but normally it would be

```
@Override public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame){
    Mat gray; 
    cvtColor(inputFrame, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    return gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such method `gray()` in the class `Mat`. If you are trying to convert the image to gray-scale, use the following code:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(src, dest, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

`inputFrame` is not a `Mat`. It has to be `CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame`. So it should be:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)
```

Comment: It depends on OpenCV version. In OpenCV 3.X `onCameraFrame()` has `Mat` parameter: [`public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame);`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/)

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko It seems like it has both: [CvCameraViewListener](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/android/CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener.html#onCameraFrame-org.opencv.core.Mat-) has `Mat inputFrame`. But [CvCameraViewListener2](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/android/CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2.html#onCameraFrame-org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame-) has `CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame`. But `inputFrame.gray()` is a part of the second one.

Comment: :) you are right: but question is about using `inputFrame.gray()` in `public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame)`, so `Imgproc.cvtColor(src, dest, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);` instead of `.gray()` is the answer.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko One could counter-argue that he is actually saying why `inputFrame.gray()` is throwing an error. And this answers it better. But really it seems like both are correct. Just depends on that `CvCameraViewListener`

Comment: :) But he didn't get error on `@Override public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame)` - this mean that the `Mat` supported as parameter.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Hmmm... that makes sense actually... maybe he confused `inputFrame`s just like we did. :D At least we got our own answers from this civil discussion. Kudos my good sir. Maybe these comments will clear things up for everyone else. :)

Comment: Agree. The correct answer should be like: "if you use OpenCV 3.X and Interface CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener for `onCameraFrame() ` then `Mat` object with no `.gray()` method is parameter of it and you should use `Imgproc.cvtColor(src, dest, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`; instead of  `inputFrame.gray()`. Or you can change Listener to   `CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2` with `onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)` and use `inputFrame.gray();` as in your source code".